# What does the convergence in probability of random variables $\{X_n\}\to \{X\}$ mean?

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

What does the convergence in probability of random variables $\{X_n\}\to \{X\}$ mean?

I interpret a random variable $X_i$ to be a function from the sample space to $\Bbb{R}$.

Then what does $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}P(|X-X_n|>\epsilon)=0$ mean? Are we calculating $|X-X_n|$ at each point in the sample space, and then saying that the values of $X$ and $X_n$ cannot differ by much?

Comment: Yes, $|X-X_n|$ is a random variable taking values in $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$. So, for example, for some points in the sample space $\Omega$ we will have that $|X-X_n|$ is greater than $\epsilon$ and for others it's less. We want the proportion (in a probabilistic sense, i.e. the measure of the set $\{\omega\in\Omega: |X-X_n| >\epsilon\}$where it occurs) of events where it's greater than $\epsilon$ to go to $0$.

Comment: @TSF- Thanks for the clarification. How does not calculate the probability of $|X-X_n|>\epsilon$ at each point though? From what I've read, this is not clear.

Comment: It's different for different problems. For me it's a bit like asking how we do solve a differential equation. This is what's going on in theory but I've never seen anyone consider individual $\omega\in\Omega$ and try to count the proportion or somehting, although it might be possible for a simple example.

Comment: @TSF- That clears it up. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The clear definition of the following fact:

**Definition (convergence in probability):**

A sequence $\{X_n\}$ of random variables is said to converge in probability to a random variable $X$ if $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}P(|X_n-X|>\epsilon)=0$$ for any $\epsilon>0$. It is denoted by $$X_n\overset{P}{\rightarrow}X$$

This means that the probability that $X_n$ differs from $X$ by any small value $\epsilon$ can be made as small as possible as we go towards $\infty$. Which is convergence in the Probabilistic sense.